# How to handle button of product list screen for different categories

Tags: flutter, dart, logic, categories, cart

Getting the same index value for product in category 1 and category 2. I saved my product data in shared preference and get data on productlist screen but getting the problem.

```
List<Product> cartItems = [];
bool tap = false;
ProductController productController = Get.find();
List<Product> wishlistItems = [];

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_loadwishlistItems();
_loadCartItems();
}

Future<void> _loadwishlistItems() async {
List<Product> items = await WishList.getwishlistItems();

QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('product')
    .where('categoryName', isEqualTo: widget.id)
    .get();

wishlistItems = List.generate(snapshot.docs.length, (index) {
  if (items.isNotEmpty && items.length > index && items[index] != null) {
    return items[index];
  } else {
    return Product(isPressed: false);
  }
});
setState(() {});
}

Future<void> _loadCartItems() async {
List<Product> items = await CartService.getCartItems();

QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('product')
    .where('categoryName', isEqualTo: widget.id)
    .get();

cartItems = List.generate(snapshot.docs.length, (index) {
  if (items.isNotEmpty && items.length > index && items[index] != null) {
    return items[index];
  } else {
    return Product(quantity: 0);
  }
});
setState(() {});
}
```

if i tap the button the quantity of product is added and shows plus minus and quantity of the product for each index. but the problem i am facing if i add product to the cart with quantity of 3 from category 1. same state is shown on the category 2 with 3 quantity. i don't know how to state this problem.kindly help.
[image: same value for different categories]

This is the logic i used in my gridview builder:

```
    cartItems[index].quantity < 1
                                      ? Center(
                                          child: ElevatedButton(
                                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                  backgroundColor: mainColor),
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  cartItems[index].quantity++;
                                                });
                                                productController.itemIncrement();
                                                CartService.addToCart(Product(
                                                    imageurl: snapshot
                                                        .data.docs[index]
                                                        .get("url"),
                                                    name: snapshot.data?.docs[index]
                                                        .get("productName"),
                                                    price: discountprice.ceil(),
                                                    discountPrice: double.tryParse(
                                                        snapshot.data?.docs[index].get(
                                                            "discountPercentage")),
                                                    quantity: 1,
                                                    isPressed: true));
                                                if (kDebugMode) {
                                                  print(
                                                      productController.itemCount);
                                                }
                                              },
                                              child: const Text('Add to cart')))
                                      : Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                          children: [
                                            IconButton(
                                                onPressed: cartItems[index]
                                                            .quantity >
                                                        1
                                                    ? () {
                                                        setState(() {
                                                          cartItems[index]
                                                              .quantity--;
                                                        });
                                                        productController
                                                            .itemDecrement();
                                                        CartService.subQuantity(
                                                            index);
                                                      }
                                                    : () {
                                                        setState(() {
                                                          cartItems[index]
                                                              .quantity--;
                                                        });
                                                        productController
                                                            .itemDecrement();
                                                        CartService.removeFromCart(
                                                            index);
                                                      },
                                                icon: Icon(
                                                  cartItems[index].quantity > 1
                                                      ? Icons.remove
                                                      : Icons.delete,
                                                  color: mainColor,
                                                )),
                                            Text(
                                              '${cartItems[index].quantity}',
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                  color: mainColor,
                                                  fontSize: 20,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                            ),
                                            IconButton(
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    cartItems[index].quantity++;
                                                  });
                                                  CartService.addQuantity(index);
                                                  productController.itemIncrement();
                                                },
                                                icon: const Icon(
                                                  Icons.add,
                                                  color: mainColor,
                                                )),
                                          ],
                                        )


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E30Jd.jpg
```